# In Android version 21 gen folder is not generating

Tags: android, sdk

I updated latest sdk version,build tools and platform tools also. when i import android appcompat v7 from android->support. It shows

> **error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.**

target version is 19. When i changed the android target version to 21 then clean the project the error got cleared but the

> gen folder is not generating automatically then java compiler is 1.7.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you first need to add the project (containing all the resources) to your java workspace. Do it as follows for the appcpompat package:

1. GO to File - New - Other (Or use Ctrl + N),
2. Choose Android - Android Project from Existing Code,
3. Choose the root directory of the appcompat package (It can be found here: sdk-directory/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat),
4. Choose `android-support-v7-appcompat` project and click finish.

Now you can add the appcompat library to your project. Just right click on the project, choose Properties and go to Android page. In the Library section click on Add and choose `android-support-v7-appcompat`.